# Elasticearch - check if Boolean keyword is in text

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

having trouble with an elasticsearch query.

So I have about 22,000 Boolean Keywords(e.g. ("stock market") ("trading"), ("ecology"|"pollution"), etc.) in an index and I want to query for those documents whose keyword can be found in a certain text.

EDIT:

mappings are such:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
                   "id": {
                          "type": "long"
                         },
                   "word": {
                          "type": "text",
                           "fields": {
                                      "keyword": {
                                                  "type": "keyword",
                                                   "ignore_above": 256
                                                 }
                                      }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

These are examples of what this index's records look like:

```
"id" : 41074
"word" : """("Technical-Vocational-Livelihood "|"TVL")  ("Track")""",
```

```
 "id" : 38684,
 "word" : """("Special Education Program")""",
```

Now, I want to filter only the documents whose "word" can be found in a specific text, E.G.

```
…Here, a student has the following options: prepare for college education, look for work, or start a business after graduation. K-12, which took effect in 2016, has four tracks: academic, technical-vocational-livelihood (TVL), arts and design and sports. “Before, when you drop out of high school, you are really a dropout; as you are expected to proceed to college or higher education…
```

Currently, I have this query:

```
GET client_keywords/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"terms": {
          "id": [
              41074,
              38684,
              ...
          ]
        }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "",
            "params": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking of filtering this through ES's simple query API, but I don't know if it's possible to invoke the simple query API through scripting.

Comment: Can you please reformulate your questions (e.g. there is no such thing like “boolean keywords”). Share your index mappings, your queries and what you like to get back.

Comment: Are you trying looking for the keywords: "AND", "OR"?

Comment: Even after reformulating your question I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Please put a little bit more care into describing the problem and formatting the code for better readability (mapping).

What do you consider as a "keyword". An Elasticsearch keyword refers to an exact match, matching every single byte of your string. Your strings look like """("Technical-Vocational-Livelihood "|"TVL")  ("Track")""", but I doubt you want to match the complete string, including double quotes, parenthesis, pipe character etc.

Also, you use a script query without a script. ???